# Java TCP Audio... Works on Linux, whitenoise on Mac

Tags: java, macos, audio, playback, javasound

I have created a TCP connection that sends Audio captured from the microphone to another computer. In my case I am using a Linux Distribution and a Macbook 10.6 laptop.

I can send the microphone feed from my Mac to the Linux box with no problems at all, it sounds really good! (I was using UDP, but the same problem occurred and it wasn't as crisp). However, when I just listen to what the Mac receives and outputs to speaker, it sounds like white noise. I cannot hear anything over it.

I have a feeling my problem may lie within my get audio format method which I have right here

```
    private AudioFormat getFormat() {
         int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
         int channels = 2;
         boolean signed = true;
         boolean bigEndian = false;
         return new AudioFormat(44100, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
    }
```

My two classes I am using for it are right here

Microphone

```
public class Microphone implements Runnable {
private TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
private final AudioFileFormat.Type WAVE = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
private InputStream inputStream;
private byte[] buffer;
private Socket socket;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private volatile boolean run;

private final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
private final int SAMPLE_INTERVAL = 2;
private final int SAMPLE_SIZE = 2;
private final int BUFFER_SIZE = SAMPLE_INTERVAL * SAMPLE_INTERVAL * SAMPLE_SIZE * 2;

private OutputStream outputStream;

private boolean isServer;

private final int PORT = 6000;
private InetAddress ipAddr;

private AudioReceiver audioReceiver;


public Microphone(boolean server) {
    try{
        ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.112");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    this.isServer = server;
    DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, getFormat());

    try {
        targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        targetDataLine.open(getFormat());
        targetDataLine.start();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
public void run() {
    run = true;
    boolean isConnected = false;
    if (isServer) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            while(!isConnected)
            {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                if(socket.isBound()) isConnected = true;

            }
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(ipAddr, PORT);
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    audioReceiver = new AudioReceiver(socket);
    Thread inputThread = new Thread(audioReceiver);
    inputThread.start();

    while (true) {
        int bytes_read = 0;
        int bytes_counted = 0;
        buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        try {
            while (run) {
                bytes_read = targetDataLine.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                if(bytes_read > 0)
                {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0,BUFFER_SIZE);
                bytes_counted += bytes_read;

                Thread.sleep(1, 0);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }

}


private AudioFormat getFormat() {
    int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
    int channels = 1;
    boolean signed = true;
    boolean bigEndian = false;
    return new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
}
```

}

Audio Receiver

```
public class Microphone implements Runnable {
private TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
private final AudioFileFormat.Type WAVE = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
private InputStream inputStream;
private byte[] buffer;
private Socket socket;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private volatile boolean run;

private final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
private final int SAMPLE_INTERVAL = 2;
private final int SAMPLE_SIZE = 2;
private final int BUFFER_SIZE = SAMPLE_INTERVAL * SAMPLE_INTERVAL * SAMPLE_SIZE * 2;

private OutputStream outputStream;

private boolean isServer;

private final int PORT = 6000;
private InetAddress ipAddr;

private AudioReceiver audioReceiver;


public Microphone(boolean server) {
    try{
        ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.112");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    this.isServer = server;
    DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, getFormat());

    try {
        targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        targetDataLine.open(getFormat());
        targetDataLine.start();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
public void run() {
    run = true;
    boolean isConnected = false;
    if (isServer) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            while(!isConnected)
            {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                if(socket.isBound()) isConnected = true;

            }
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(ipAddr, PORT);
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    audioReceiver = new AudioReceiver(socket);
    Thread inputThread = new Thread(audioReceiver);
    inputThread.start();

    while (true) {
        int bytes_read = 0;
        int bytes_counted = 0;
        buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        try {
            while (run) {
                bytes_read = targetDataLine.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                if(bytes_read > 0)
                {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0,BUFFER_SIZE);
                bytes_counted += bytes_read;

                Thread.sleep(1, 0);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }

}


private AudioFormat getFormat() {
    int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
    int channels = 1;
    boolean signed = true;
    boolean bigEndian = false;
    return new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
}
```

}

Comment: What processor is your mac running? If it's an Intel x86, I believe it should be using little endian. If it's power-pc, it should be big endian.

Comment: There seem to be two copies of the `Microphone` class and no receiver class!

Comment: Oh Woops greg-449! I will have to re edit this when I am at a computer. 

Sager89, so on my mac (power-pc), I just change it to bigendian? Or should I be sending out big endian as well from Linux? (I ask the last part because I am not at the computer right now, so I can not test it quite yet)